# Type conversion error when returning pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, reference, type-conversion

Id like to return a pointer(or reference to one) instead of a reference to my value. But I keep getting conversion errors.

I tried changing the return type to Node* but it doesnt recognize it as a known type since Node is a struct.

I'm having a hard time understanding these conversion erros clearly when using templates. I havent found a clear answer to these conversions yet.

```
error: cannot convert ‘TreeAVL<int>::Node*’ to ‘const int*’ in return
```

```
template<class T>
const T* TreeAVL<T>::find(Node* node, const T& element) const {
    if (node == nullptr)
        return nullptr;
    if (element == node->value)
        return &(node->value);
        //return &(node);            <<<< what I want to return if found.
    ...
}
```

Comment: Your `find` function is typed to return a pointer to `T`, but you want to return a pointer to a `Node<T>`? Then change the return type?

Comment: Do you intend to return (a pointer to) a `value` (which is of type `T`) or a `node` (which is of type `Node*`)? In your code it seems you don't really know.

Comment: Type conversion is the least of the problems here. If your compiler is not telling you that you have undefined behavior, update your compiler. `find()` is completely broken, and on half of the execution paths it does not return anything.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik What do you mean exactly? Its a recursive method so its calls itself again in the second part.

Comment: @user17732522 Well yeah I tried it before `template<class T>
Node* TreeAVL<T>::find(Node* node, const T& element) const` but it doesnt recognize Node as a type. Its a struct so I dont know why it should.

Comment: @Human-Compiler I tried it before but it doesnt recognize Node as a type since its a struct. Is there a way to change that or Im missing something here?

Comment: Fyi, "Its a recursive method" - each of those recursed calls returns something (just like the active call that calls *them*). So where are you reaping those recursed call valued and what are you doing with them thereafter? Hint: the naked `find` invokes are basically worthless until you start doing something with what they return. Regarding your problem, your current code returns a pointer to tree node value (the address of a member var in the Node). If you want to return a pointer to the node itself (that holds the value), you need a different return type.

Comment: @Olivia22 You just have to qualify the type name in the out-of-line definition: `template<class T> typename TreeAVL<T>::Node* TreeAVL<T>::find(Node* node, const T& element) const`.

Comment: @user17732522 @user17732522 I had to modify it to `typename TreeAVL<T>::Node find(Node* node, const T& element) const;` tbh Id have never guessed something like this. Now I have an error for the return of the nullptr. so not sure how to approach this haha

Comment: @Olivia22 you MUST declare the return type as `Node*` instead of `Node`. Add the `*` exactly as user17732522 showed you. You can't return a node by value. And then change `return &(node->value);` to `return node;` and add `return` in front of the recursive `find()` calls. Also, one of your recursive `find()` calls needs to use `node->left` instead of `node->right`.

Comment: Recursion does not work the way you think it works. If there's a recursive function that returns a value, and it calls itself, but ...doesn't do anything with the returned value, and it, itself, returns without returning a value (exactly like the shown `find` does), well... assuming your compiler will agree to compile this without an error, the end result will not work, C++ does not work this way.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the conversion error,

```
error: cannot convert ‘TreeAVL<int>::Node*’ to ‘const int*’ in return
```

You have to look at the definition of the template that produces this error, which would be something like:

```
// A function returning const T*
template<class T>
const T* TreeAVL<T>::find(Node* node, const T& element) const {
    // OK, any T* can be a nullptr:
    if (node == nullptr)
        return nullptr;
    // But here the return value is a TreeAVL<T>::Node*, which is not
    // necessarily convertible to any T*
    if (element == node->value)
        return node;
    // ...
}
```

So you get an error as soon as you use this template with an incompatible `T`, such as `int` in your example. If you want to return a pointer to a node instead, the function *must* be declared to do so, and its return statements must all be compatible with that.

Also, if you want to avoid the cumbersome typename, you can also use `const auto*`, or make the definition inline and specify it as `const Node*`.